# Redmi Note 9 Pro Stuck in boot loop

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, unbricking, developer-options

about 2 days ago my phone completely died (battery) so i plugged it in overnight. when i tried powering it on in the morning it was getting stuck on the MIUI animation, just after the powered by android screen. after multiple attempts to restart it by long pressing the power button it entered the boot menu to try a reboot from there... no Joy. so i then tried wiping the data to see if that would help. it gets to about 3% and then the phone reboots again getting stuck in the same place.

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/j-jith/0c4950e8020d9bed0c3104608b07a49d) but am getting

`no permissions (missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]    fastboot`

I then tried using the `Mi Unlock tool` but the device is not showing up in that when I plug it in.
Ive read somewhere then that i need some developer settings set in the developer options but i honestly don't remember if I ever even unlocked them on this phone as i dont do any android development any more but I may have them turned on.
when the phone is plugged in i can see it in device manager as `Android` with a yellow warning triangle visible.
I could really do, any old devices i have to tide me over have laughably short battery lifes so could really do with getting this sorted.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE**
I followed the above gist on my linux machiene as that is where i had the android dev stuff installed and the Mi Unlock on my windows pc which does not have any android dev tools installed

Comment: this question needs more focused to single problem. do you want to fix boot loop, factory reset device or unlock bootloader

Comment: @alecxs my only concern is getting my phone working again, so whatever is the easiest means to achieve that.

Comment: check bootloader unlock is allowed `fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability` and unlock with [XiaoMiTool v2](https://www.xda-developers.com/xiaomitool-windows-mod-xiaomi-smartphone) (linux build) or set *get_unlock_ability 1* manually with [edl.py](https://github.com/bkerler/edl#for-generic-unlocking) (patched [firehose loader](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4192357) and [EDL cable](http://xiaomitips.com/guide/miui-deep-flash-engineering-cable-solution-to-non-edl-device) required). or flash [stock ROM](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/curtana) on locked bootloader

Comment: @alecxs can you explain 'flash stock ROM on locked bootloader'
I have tried installing the google ABD driver via the android studio sdk manage but this made no difference and the device is still not recognized by the miflash_unlock tool. i have been looking around a lot for miui fast boot drivers and any thing that I've found that might be useful but all I seem to find is questionable looking websites

Comment: @alecxs when i say makes no difference, yes windows as thats where i said i had the issue with the driver (yellow triangle), yes the device is on the fastboot screen with the bunny. yes i did install the Get the Google USB Driver via android studio sdk manager as i mentioned in my last comment.
`fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability` is returning 0.
next break i get i will clean up the comments and refactor the question

Comment: okay so you can't use Mi Unlock tool then. try to switch into [EDL mode](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3398718) from fastboot (other methods such as deep flash cable or test point exist). if succeed, for windows install Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 Driver (yellow triangle). Your drivers are ready for [Xiaomi MI Flash Tool](https://androidmtk.com/use-xiaomi-mi-flash-tool) now, it can flash in fastboot or EDL mode (alternatives: [QPST](https://androidmtk.com/use-qpst-flash-tool)/[QFIL](https://androidmtk.com/use-qualcomm-flash-image-loader-qfil))

Comment: While I don't have the solution for this issue, AFAIK, the Google USB driver should only be applicable for Google devices (Nexus & Pixel series). For other manufacturers, [OEM USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb) may be a more appropriate resource.